# Sum up multiple arrays with different keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to sum up the values of multiple arrays but with no success. I feel like my brain can't take it anymore therefore I need some help or tips.

This is the best I've got so far:

```
$bani= array();
$iduri=array();
$total=0;
foreach($qp as $luna) {

    $nsd_id=$luna['nsd_id'];  // different ids every foreach
    $nsd_amount=$luna['nsd_amount']; // different values every foreach

    $nsd_id=explode("@",$nsd_id); // this makes them arrays
   $nsd_amount=explode("@",$nsd_amount); // same , it makes them arrays

    $iduri=array_merge($iduri,$nsd_id); // i tried getting making an array of all the ids it finds
    for($x=0;$x<count($iduri);$x++){
            $bani[$iduri[$x]] += intval($nsd_amount[$iduri[$x]]);
            $total += intval($nsd_amount[$x]);
        }

}
$iduri=array_unique($iduri,SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($iduri);
```

I've tried making an array of every ID it finds and then based on it's position, to sum it to the array.

It does sum something indeed but I'm not getting the right value and also tons of undefined offsets.

I feel like there is an easier way than all this and I'd really appreciate some advices.

Thanks!
[image of the columns in the DB i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGAEO.png)

I'd appreciate if the result could be an array of:

```
Array ( 
[1] => 0 
[2] => 2500
[3] => 62000 
[4] => etc 
[5] => etc 
[12] => etc 
[14] => etc )
```

(id-s as keys and summed up values as value of the corresponding id)

var_export of qp

```
Mysqli_result::__set_state(Array( 'Current_field' => NULL, 'Field_count' => NULL, 'Lengths' => NULL, 'Num_rows' => NULL, 'Type' => NULL, ))
```

var_export of $value inside foreach(partial)

```
Array ( 'Id' => '329', 'Month' => 'May', 'Year' => '2019', 'Empid' => '124', 'Addedby' => 'PMSCLT10002', 'Nsd_id' => '1@2@3@4@5@12@14@15', 'Nsd_amount' => '0@0@0@0@0@0@4000@0', )
Array ( 'Id' => '303', 'Month' => 'April', 'Year' => '2019', 'Empid' => '124', 'Addedby' => 'PMSCLT10002', 'Nsd_id' => '1@2@3@4@5@12@14@15', 'Nsd_amount' => '0@0@2000@0@0@500@0@0', )
```

.. etc

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Edited my question. Basically an array with keys that contains the nsd_id and the summed up values corresponding to each $nsd_id

Comment: Given the first row in your table, what should the array look like using those values???

Comment: @AbraCadaver check the new edit. thanks!

Comment: @BrianNova Please check my answer, let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet you can do,

```
$nsdIds = [];
$result = [];
foreach ($qp as $key => $value) {
    // exploding Nsd_ids
    $nsdTemp = explode("@", $value['Nsd_id']);
    // exploding nsd_amounts
    $nsdAmount = explode("@", $value['Nsd_amount']);
    // saving all new nsd ids and only keep unique nsd ids
    $nsdIds = array_unique(array_merge($nsdIds, $nsdTemp));
    // I am now combining keeping nsd id as key and nsd amount as its value
    $temp1 = array_combine($nsdTemp, $nsdAmount);

    foreach ($nsdIds as $value1) {
        // for latest php version
        // $temp1 contains keys of nsd ids
        //  value1 contains nsdids we are sure that it will be in nsdids as we are already merging those ids
        //  then fetching amounf for that nsdids
        //$result[$value1] = ($result[$value1] ?? 0) + $temp1[$value1];
        // for php version less than 7
        $result[$value1] = (!empty($result[$value1]) ? $result[$value1] : 0) +  
                            (!empty($temp1[$value1]) ? $temp1[$value1] : 0);
    }
}
print_r($result);die;
```

[Demo for php 7](https://3v4l.org/qnK1X) and [demo for < php 7](https://3v4l.org/1Ymh7).

Comment: thank you for the answer! unfortunately I'm still getting tons of undefined offsets and the print output is Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [12] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 )

Comment: Ok, can you please update your question with `var_export($qp);`?

Comment: @BrianNova I have attached working demo for your case and its showing result. please check demo [link](https://3v4l.org/qnK1X).

Comment: in your demo please check the version using php 5.6 -- $result[$value1] = (!empty($result[$value1]) ? $result[$value1] : 0) + $result[$temp1[$value1]];

Comment: I have attached both the demo version wise and made changes in my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! Is there any way to avoid undefined offsets on the higher values? (key 12 and up)

Comment: *Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.*

Comment: Is there any way to avoid undefined offsets on the higher values? (key 12 and up)

Comment: apply isset for that, that will solve your problem. I updated my answer, you may facing issue in that.

Comment: thanks you! you just saved my 3 hours spent on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So long as `nsd_id` and `nsd_amount` in the same row have the same number of values between the `@` then this should work.  If not then you need an `isset` to check for `$nsd_amount[$key]`:

```
foreach($qp as $luna) {
    $nsd_id = explode("@", $luna['nsd_id']);
    $nsd_amount = explode("@", $luna['nsd_amount']);

    foreach($nsd_id as $key => $id) {
        if(isset($result[$id])) {
            $result[$id] += $nsd_amount[$key];
        } else {
            $result[$id]  = $nsd_amount[$key];
        }
    }   
}
```